# How long Cardano node takes to be installed?

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node, nix, node, install

I'm running this script but it takes hours !

curl https://hydra.iohk.io/build/9941098/reproduce | bash

Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the binary cache setup referenced here most likely:
https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/master/doc/getting-started/building-the-node-using-nix.md#iohk-binary-cache

Answer (score 1):

if you want to install Cardano Node,
building the node :
this commands will actually build/compile the node and will take around 40-45 minutes.

cd ~/git

git clone https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node

cd cardano-node

git fetch --tags --all

git checkout 1.33.0

echo -e "package cardano-crypto-praos\n  flags: -external-libsodium-vrf" > cabal.project.local

$CNODE_HOME/scripts/cabal-build-all.sh -o

At the end, check the cardano-cli and cardano-node version

cardano-cli --version

cardano-node --version

Answer (score 0):

The time varies depending on a lot of factors. These can range from the capabilities of your computer to the current length of the chain. For this reason, it's hard to give a blanket answer as it always varies.

But there is a silver lining, you can drastically reduce the build time by using the binary cache setup by iohk:  https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/master/doc/getting-started/building-the-node-using-nix.md#iohk-binary-cache

Hope this was helpful.

But you can figure it out.

Step 1) using CardanoScan to figure out the `current epoch` and the `current slot` it will also display the `number of slots in an epoch`.

Step 2) let the build process continue for a while a time how long it takes to reach `X` slot. The larger the `X` you chose the better the approximation. The amount of time is called `t`.

Step 3) ((`current epoch` x  `slots in an epoch` ) + `Current Slot`) * `t`/`X` approx `How long it will take`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just install the Deadules Wallet. Due to it being a full node, it must install the Cardano node in the background. The reason I suggest this is that it's easier to find documentation and youtube videos for Deadules than it is for building the node from the repo.

You can do all the same stuff with the Deadules node as the one from the repo because they are basically the same thing. This includes running a local server that acts as a query API to the blockchain.